# Display user input image without saving it to a folder

Tags: php

How can I display an image and pass it as an input parameter in an executable in php without saving the image in a folder. The user gives the image path as input and I am using ajax to display the image when it is selected when I save it to a folder it works but how can I display it without saving it in a folder? My code now is

```
     move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],"upload/".$_FILES["file"]["name"]);
                        //echo "Stored in "."upload/".$_FILES["file"]["name"];
                        echo "<img src='upload/".$_FILES["file"]["name"]."' class='preview'>";
```

I tried

```
   <img src=$_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]. class='preview'>
```

but it didnt work. As I will have thousands of input from thousands of user I dont want to save it. Is there any optimised and efficient method to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The `src` attribute of the `<img>` tag should be an URL accessible by the client.

You try to give a local path (ex: `path/to/your/file.jpg`) of a temporary file as URL, it will not working.

info: The uploaded image is save on the local disk on a temp directory, and could be deleted by PHP later.

If you want to show the image without moving it at a place reacheable by a URL, you can try to load its content as base64 content

```
$imagedata = file_get_contents($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]);
$base64 = base64_encode($imagedata);
```

and use in your HTML

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64, <?php echo $base64; ?>" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, its not possible to show image without saving it. You could try to save the image in temp folder on the server side and clean this folder periodically to avoid much space consumption.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can show the image without saving it.

You need to save the file either to the filesystem or to memory if you want to later output

Your problem here is that $_FILES only exists in the script that the image was sent to. so when you initiate another http request for img source, php no longer has any clue what file your trying to read.

You need a way to tell which image to be read on http request.

One thing you can do is that you can save the file in a place accessible by the client and then just have php delete it after you output it. So once the image is outputted it will be deleted and no longer be existing in the file system.

Another approach would be to get the image from the memory by directly writing the contents to httpresponse.

You can do this way

```
$image            = file_get_contents($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]);
$enocoded_data    = base64_encode($image);
```

and when you show your image tag :

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64, <?php echo $enocoded_data    ; ?>" />
```

Hope any of these helps you